# SQL内で条件によってプラスされる数値を変えたい。

Tags: php, cakephp, sql

現在、下記のようにProduct.priceにpvs.idの合計数を足しているのですが、
下記に、
pvs.idの合計が10のときにProduct.priceに+1、
pvs.idの合計が20のときにProduct.priceに+2、
pvs.idの合計が30のときにProduct.priceに+3、
・・・・
pvs.idの合計が100のときにProduct.priceに+10、

と順次足されていくようにしたいのですが、SQL内に記述は可能ですか？
また、可能だとしたらどのようなコードになりますか？

Model/Product.php

```
    public $virtualFields = array(
        'product_price'  => '
                Product.price + (10 * (SELECT coalesce(COUNT(pvs.id), 0) FROM pvs WHERE product_id = Product.id))
        )',
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'product_price'  => '
            Product.price + ((SELECT coalesce(COUNT(pvs.id), 0) FROM pvs WHERE product_id = Product.id) / 10)
    )',
);
```

で解決しました。